# Dell Precision 3630 tower 16 x 2 + 32 x 2 GB RAM Configuration is allowed?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a Dell Precision 3630 tower with an Intel i7 8700 processor (Intel C246 chipset). The PC also has NVIDIA P1000 4 GB GPU.

Among the four DIMM slots, two are populated with 16 GB  DDR4 2666 MHz RAM.

Can I now add 32 GB x 2 RAM in those two empty slots to make it a total of 96 GB RAM? Also, if it possible to have (16GB x 2 + 32 GB x 2) combination, is it possible to add those 32 GB RAMs with 3200 MHz or it is mandatory to use 2666 MHz 32 GB RAMs in the present configuration?

Comment: Any memory you install, no matter the size density will run at the slowest frequency of any installed module.  So buying 3200 MHz memory will run at 2666 Mhz due to the other set you have installed.

Comment: Please also mention whether 16 x 2 + 32 x 2 GB RAM configuration will be supported in my machine without any issue?